# jquery draggable work only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a list of images and every image lies inside a div element.While generating the images i bind the draggable event to each img element.i.e. `$('#optionImage_'+ next +'').draggable();`

where next assigns unique id to each img element.When i drag any image it starts dragging but when i do the mouse up it does not allow to drag again and disable all js functionality on that page means it raise error.

Please suggest me i am using jquery 1.7 and jquery ui 1.8.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: $('#optionImage_'+ next +'').draggable(); is the only coding i am binding draggable with every image element.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. My code looked like this

```
$('<td>'+document.getElementById("hideditname").value+'</td>').appendTo('#etr1').draggable( {cursor: 'move',helper:'clone', start: edittabclass });
```

I was facing the same problem you were having.

Then I changed the code like this-

```
$('<td>'+document.getElementById("hideditname").value+'</td>').appendTo('#etr1').draggable( {cursor: 'move', start: edittabclass, revert:'true' });
```

Then the problem got solved.

You can also remove the revert element.

Comment: so you removed the helper option?